# Pass JsonResponse to IntentService

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, httpresponse

I have My `MainActivity` and I can get response very well :

```
 JSONObject responseVal = responseObj.getJSONObject("data");
                message = responseVal.getString("id");
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + message);
```

and I have `IntentService` and want to pass that `message` value to it.

I tried with `SharedPreferences` and also with `intentPutExtra` but it doesn't work.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store that message into the application than user sharedprefrences other wise use `putextra` and `getIntent.getextra()` method.

on your click event

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,yourclass.class);
i.putExtra("demo",message);
```

In `yourclass.class`

```
String mes=getIntent().getStringExtra("demo");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For sending `message` to your `IntentService`, try this:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourIntentService.class);
   intent.putExtra("message", message);
   startService(intent);
   ```
2. To receive the `message` in `IntentService`, try this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
       ........
   }
   ```